# how to download references from task details in ms graph?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, office365, adal, microsoft-planner

how to download references from task details in ms graph?

I have the following reference from a task detail (plannerTaskDetails resource type):
`https://my_domain.sharepoint.com/sites/HR2/Shared Documents/2.csv?web=1`

and I want to download the file but I get:
`'401 UNAUTHORIZED'`

I have the following delegated permissions:

- https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.Read.All
- https://graph.microsoft.com/Group.Read.All
- https://graph.microsoft.com/Sites.Read.All

I do not know if I have to add another permission. Any help is appreciated.

The actual value of the reference is `'https%3A//my_domain%2Esharepoint%2Ecom/sites/HR2/Shared Documents/2%2Ecsv?web=1'` to get the url I have used:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote

url = 'https%3A//my_domain%2Esharepoint%2Ecom/sites/HR2/Shared Documents/2%2Ecsv?web=1'

sp_url = unquote(url)
sp_url

# 'https://my_domain.sharepoint.com/sites/HR2/Shared Documents/2.csv?web=1'
```

If I put the URL in a browser where I'm logged in I can download the file.

Comment: Hi did you have a chance to look into my answer? Do you have any other concerns?

Comment: @AllenWu thx you so much for your response, I will write down an answer later, I manage to download the file, I had the group_id  so I used: `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group_id}/drive/root:/2.csv`  seems like all the files from planner tasks are saved in group root so I can use /drive/root:/<my_file_name> (or alias how is found in plannerTaskDetails)

Comment: @AllenWu and since I used /groups/ I just need the following permission https://graph.microsoft.com/Group.Read.Al, if I'm wrong please correct me

Comment: I think you are right:)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use this url format to download the file with Microsoft Graph. The access token is for Microsoft Graph but your url is for `https://my_domain.sharepoint.com`.

Please refer to [Download a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

You should use `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/sites/{siteId}/drive/root:/{item-path}:/content`.

It will return a `302 Found` response redirecting to a pre-authenticated **download URL** for the file. This is the same URL available through the @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl property on the DriveItem.

Then you can use this download url to download the file.

But based on my latest test, `/content` doesn't work for me. I'm not sure if it works for you. So there is another method here.

In your case, I assume that HR2 is a subsite under `my_domain.sharepoint.com`.

Then the real requests should be:

1. Call `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/my_domain.sharepoint.com/sites` to list the subsites and find the id of "HR2".
2. Call `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{id of "HR2"}/drive/root:/2.csv`.

In the response, there is a `@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl` property. You can directly use that url to download the file.

If HR2 is another site collection, the requests should be:

1. Call `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/my_domain.sharepoint.com:/sites/HR2` to get the id of "HR2".

The subsequent steps are the same as subsite.